# Android emulator works, device dont

Tags: android, android-activity

Can someone tell me why the below piece of code doesn't work on real devices but work on emulator? When I say it doesn't work, it means that when I enter this activity it throws: "The application stopped working".

```
TextView total_price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total_price_products);
Double main_value = 0.00;
for(int i = 0; i <= sP.size() - 1; i++){
    String[] values = sP.get(i).toString().split("::");
    Double price = Double.parseDouble(value[3].toString());
    main_value += price;
}
total_price.setText(String.valueOf(main_value) + "€");
```

I know that the error comes from here, because I did a debug step by step on Eclipse removing all lines of code and going one by one line..untill I found that the error was there.

In emulator, everythings runs normally, without errors or alerts. I also put Logs to see what's going on, and this is the log:

```
Log.e("SP : ", sP.get(i).toString()); 
// Returns: 1432::Google Company::ASB32AAF3::14.12::2
// which means:
// id::product:model:price:quantity
Log.e("Price : ", String.valueOf(price));
// Returns: 14.12
Log.e("Main Value : ", String.valueOf(main_value));
// Returns: 14.12
// This last value it's correct, since I already 
// put in the price field the sum of the original price plus quantity
```

Any ideas or possible solutions? What do you recommend? Thanks.

**Edit: Solved.**

Seems that our devices treats the Double fields as "," instead of ".".
That said, the only thing to change is:

```
Double price = Double.parseDouble(value[3].toString().replace(",", "."));
```

Comment: Did you get any errors in the LogCat?

Comment: at which line you are getting the error

Comment: @buczek as I said, I dont have any errors or alerts (in logcat).
I found that the line causing this error is this: `Double price = Double.parseDouble(value[3].toString());`

Comment: I think I just found the solution, hold a second.